# How to emulate lists in HTML?

Tags: html, html-lists

I'm converting a word document into HTML by hand so that it'll look nice when published on the Amazon Kindle. However, I'm having trouble getting the table of contents to look right.

Basically, I want the TOC to look something like what you'd get with an ordered list, but with custom list items:

Table of Contents 
Preface: My Example

1. The First Chapter
2. Apples
3. Yadda Yadda...

Epiogue: The End
Appendix

How can I get the "Preface", "Epilogue", and "Appendix" labels to align themselves with the "1", "2" and "3" in the list? How can I get the preface and epilogue titles (i.e., "My Example", and "The End") to align with all the rest of the chapter titles? I realize it probably can't be an actual HTML list tag, but how might I achieve the appearance?

Note - this must render on a Kindle. No javascript or anything fancy.

- EDIT:

I'm sorry if something like this has been asked before. I can't figure out a concise way to phrase this question, which makes searching for it difficult.

Comment: To have it align perfectly, I fear you'll just have to use `<table>` tag with two columns: left column for the numbers and "Preface" and "Epilogue" and right column with the items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say I've had experience formatting HTML specifically for rendering on the Kindle but the follwing basic HTML and CSS should work.

**HTML:**

```
<h2>Table of Contents</h2>
<ol id="toc">
    <li class="no">Preface: My Example</li>
    <li value="1">The First Chapter</li>
    <li>Apples</li>
    <li>Yadda Yadda...</li>
    <li class="no">Epilogue: The End</li>
    <li class="no">Appendix</li>
</ol>
```

**CSS:**

```
#toc {margin:0; padding:0; }
#toc li { margin:0 0 .5em 1.25em; }
#toc li.no { margin-left:0; list-style:none; }
```

**Demo:** [jsfiddle.net/BdfEE](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/BdfEE/)

It uses a deprecated `value` attribute on the second `<li>` but if it works then great. If not you can [try the CSS method](http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/make-ol-list-start-from-number-different-than-1-using-css.html) of changing the numbering of an ordered list, however I'd imagine this possibly not working, depending on Kindle's CSS capabilities.

Comment: This looks perfect. Thank you. Not exactly what I asked for (i.e. "My Example" and "The End" don't align with "Apples" and "Yadda Yadda..."), but on second thought what I asked for might look sorta weird. It's late now, so I'll test it tomorrow to see how it renders on Kindle.

Comment: @Cybis: Ahh, right. My fault for not reading properly. As Shadow Wizard said, a table is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

put them in an unordered list with no bullet marker then they should align with the other list

`<ul style='list-style-type: none;'>`

Comment: Except I want the bullet marker. I don't want to just have the chapter titles listed in the TOC. I want the chapter numbers too and indented the way you normally see in books.